# Почему после добавления wpf на winform не отображается png рисунок на кнопке?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Доброго времени суток! Ребят у меня такая проблема. Не отображаются картинки на кнопках.
Имеется [элемент WPF](http://cs614828.vk.me/v614828511/a73a/rUGZaMJn8co.jpg), типа редактор .rtf. Когда добавляю его [на форму](http://cs614828.vk.me/v614828511/a753/ekJTza21lCI.jpg), почему то картинки не отображаются. а обращаюсь к картинкам так `<Image Source="Images\editcut.png"/>`  Может кто знает почему так и как исправить?

Comment: Эээ... Ваше приложение всё же WPF или WinForms?

Comment: Приложение WinForms, а я в него добавляю элемент UserControl XAML.

Comment: Все вопрос закрыт! Надо было указать в Свойствах добавленного ресурса "Действие при сборке\Resource".  http://www.cyberforum.ru/attachments/387689d1397273891